# Android - Checking commitContent image-keyboard support

Tags: android, image, keyboard

I'm working on a image keyboard.

Been running around with this, looking at [Image Keyboard Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html), and docs for related classes. I'm successfully able to check for mime types (in this case image/gif), but I don't think its indicative of the input being able to accept rich content. I need this so I can run a fallback to share the image instead.

The "I don't think its indicative of the input being able to accept rich content" occurs in my last use case:

- Default Messaging app: image/gif support is not detected, image
  keyboard functionality is disabled.
- Google Hangouts: image/gif support is detected,
  and the gif image I select successfully gets posted.
- Slack: image/gif support is detected,
  InputConnectionCompat.commitContent() returns true, but no images are
  posted.

How do I verify that rich content is accepted in the target app?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi You can verify by the following method

 private boolean isCommitContentSupported(@NonNull String mimeType) {
        if (getCurrentInputEditorInfo() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        final InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!validatePackageName(getCurrentInputEditorInfo())) {
            return false;
        }

        final String[] supportedMimeTypes = EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        for (String supportedMimeType : supportedMimeTypes) {
            if (ClipDescription.compareMimeTypes(mimeType, supportedMimeType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what code for validatePackageName ?